# Getting data attribute in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to get the data attribute from this:

`<button ng-click="EditPlayer(name, position, number, age)" id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-successes" data-playerid="{{player.id}}">Save</button>`

In my angular controller I have:

```
$scope.EditPlayer = function(name, position, number, age) {

    var player_id = $(this).data('playerid');

    console.log(player_id);

    var player = new Player(name, position, number, age);

    $http({
        method : "PUT",
        url : 'api.php/players/'+player_id,
        data: JSON.stringify(player),
    }).then(function mySucces(player) {
        $scope.players.push(player);
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.showError = response.statusText;
    });
};
```

I need to get the attribute so I can target each player_id for an update (PUT request). The problem is that `$(this).data(player_id)` is returning undefined.

Comment: From the way you're setting data-playerid="{{player.id}}" and the method on the same button, it means u should have access to the "player" object from the controller. You can do player_id = $scope.player.id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass it as another argument to the function

```
<button ng-click="EditPlayer(name, position, number, age, player.id)" id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-successes" data-playerid="{{player.id}}">Save</button>
```

then

```
$scope.EditPlayer = function(name, position, number, age,player_id) {
    console.log(player_id)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!